# How to prompt to open, save or cancel a pdf file in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have a set of pdf files stored in a sql database. I downloaded the 2 key information (ReportIdent and Date) into a gridview. 
I am using the unique ReportIdent as a link to select and open the pdf file.
When the user clicks on the ReportIdent, I would like to have the prompt to open, save or cancel the pdf file.
When I run this code it downloads the pdf file without prompting me with the open, save or cancel option.  I have search and tried different ways but I still don't get the prompt.

Here is my code behind to show the pdf report:

```
string query = "select * from dbo.MonthlyReportPDF where ReportIdent    = '"+id+"'";
SqlCommand queryCommand = new SqlCommand(query, RptConn);
SqlDataReader queryCommandReader = queryCommand.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Load(queryCommandReader);

string myRpt = dataTable.Rows[0]["ReportIdent"].ToString();
byte[] documentBytes = (byte[])dataTable.Rows[0]["DocFile"];

if (documentBytes != null)
{
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Dispositon", "attachment; filename=" + myRpt);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", documentBytes.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(documentBytes);

Response.End();
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
}
else
{
LblError.Visible = true;
LblError.Text = Report ID "+ myRpt + "not found.";            
}
```

Here is my Default.aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMonthlyRpt" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ReportIdent">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Report ID">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
OnClick="ShowReport"
Text='<%# Eval("ReportIdent") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Report Date">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval"RptDate">'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You correctly send the `Content-Disposition` header, so the problem is not on your side. The browser is probably configured to save directly, rather than prompt the user. And of course, your app can't change the browser's configuration...

Comment: My bad.  I was missing the letter "i" from the word Disposition.  Once I corrected the spelling, it now prompted me with the open, save and cancel option.  Sorry to bother you guys with this.  But I do have a question: is it necessary for me to add the "Content-Length" header?

Comment: @esant, it's not mandatory, but it allows the client to know how much data there is to download, so it can display the download progress.